# JBoss domain dynamic port offset configuration

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I cannot seem to get configuring port-offsets via properties file on the domain managed setup to start multiple server instances in a server group.

I have the following configuration in `host.xml`:

```
<servers>
    <server name="instance-one" group="main-server-group" auto-start="true">
       <socket-bindings port-offset="${jboss.instance1.offset}"/>
    </server>
    <server name="instance-two" group="main-server-group" auto-start="true">
        <!-- server-two avoids port conflicts by incrementing the ports in
             the default socket-group declared in the server-group -->
        <socket-bindings port-offset="${jboss.instance2.offset}"/>
    </server>
</servers>
```

The properties are configured via properties file (`custom-domain.properties`):

```
jboss.domain.base.dir=custom-domain
jboss.instance1.offset=10300
jboss.instance2.offset=20300
```

And I try to startup the domain using

> ./domain.sh -P=custom-domain.properties

The problem is that `jboss.instance1.offset` and `jboss.instance2.offset` are not being applied to the corresponding properties in `host.xml`. If I have hardcoded values in the `host.xml` it appears to start up instance 1 and instance 2 on the hardcoded port offsets.

Does custom property configuration not work in domain setup?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try adding a default value to the expression. e.g. `${jboss.instance2.offset:50}`

Comment: No luck, tried that and it did not work either.

Comment: What JBoss AS 7 version?

Comment: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final - http://download.jboss.org/jbossas/7.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.tar.gz

Comment: Have you tried using -Djboss.instance1.offset=10300 ... ?

Comment: As far as I can tell it should be supported in that version. Is it give you any errors?

Comment: Host Controller] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
Host Controller]       at org.jboss.as.host.controller.parsing.HostXml.parseServerSocketBindings(HostXml.java:1168) [jboss-as-host-controller-7..1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]

Comment: I tried the -D option and that did not work either. The funny thing is I can get to extrapolate properties in the standalone mode (standalone.sh -P=<properties_file>. May be I am missing something real obvious.